# Change value in input component on rerendering

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-visualforce

I have an `<apex:dataTable value="{!dtos}" var="dto">`. There I have

```xml
<apex:column>
  <apex:facet name="header">rrr</apex:facet>
  <apex:outputPanel id="rrr">
    <apex:selectList id="rrrr" value="{!dto.rrr}" multiselect="false" size="1">
      <apex:selectOptions id="rrrrr" value="{!rrrrr}"/>
      <apex:actionSupport id="rrrrrr" event="onchange"  immediate="false"
                          reRender="ddd, ccc"
                          status="actionStatus"/>
    </apex:selectList>
  </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:column>
```

and two more guys

```xml
<apex:column>
  <apex:facet name="header">Description</apex:facet>
  <apex:outputPanel id="ddd">
    <apex:input value="{!dto.ddd}" type="text"
                id="dddd"/>
  </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:column>

<apex:column>
  <apex:facet name="header">Cost Rate</apex:facet>
  <apex:outputPanel id="ccc">
    <apex:outputText value="{0, number, currency}">
      <apex:param value="{!dto.cccc}"/>
    </apex:outputText>
  </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:column>
```

So. Description is not updated on picklist change and Cost Rate is.

In controller I have

```java
class DTOClass {
  public String rrr {
    get;
    set {
      if (rrr != value) {
        rrr = value;
        ddd = 'asdf';
        ccc = 13;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is inside of aBunchOfIdsHere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an apex method in controller. On change of picklist try like below-

```xml
<apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!apexMethodName}" rerender="ddd,ccc"/>
```

and set the value of Description and Cost Rate in controller method.

Comment: I must say it was not obvious for me that a method should be created in order to get input fields updated...